# Django Celery: manage.py celeryd returns "Unknown Command"

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to setup Celery with Django ORM as backend.

I've installed all required packages(django-celery, djkombu), done everything specified by [the docs](http://ask.github.com/celery/tutorials/otherqueues.html), ran syncdb to generate necessary DB tables.

Still, when I'm trying to launch Celery through manage.py command, I'm getting an 'Unknown Command' error.

```
python manage.py celeryd
Unknown command: 'celeryd'
```

I think I'm missing some crucial detail but can't figure out what.

[This is how my settings.py file look like.](http://pastie.org/1692202) Can anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Doesn't look like you have djcelery anywhere in your installed apps

> Using django-celery
>
> To enable django-celery for your
>   project you need to add djcelery to
>   INSTALLED_APPS:
>
> INSTALLED_APPS += ("djcelery", )

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery#documentation

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but... mmmm, where does one add to INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: @HelgiHrafnGunnarsson settings.py

Comment: Can we start the celery without `djcelery` . As celery 3.1.25 seems to compatible with Django 1.10.7 ? I am getting an error `unknown command celery ` when I removed djcelery from settings. Thanks in advance.